# Getting SQL exception in where clause while inserting data in database through java

Tags: java, mysql

I want to store the password for required ID using java. Everything is working fine except that I am getting this Exception

```
"SQL Exception thrown: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(Pass_word) set Pass_word = 'pass' where ID = 2' at line 1".
```

I am getting this exception only in update query but not in select query.I am using Eclipse. Can anyone tell me what I am doing is wrong?

```
 import java.sql.DriverManager;
    import java.sql.Connection;
    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.sql.Statement;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class information {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
             String password;
                ResultSet rs;
                String queryString;
                int x=1;
            try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection conn = null;
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/onlineexam","root", "batch12@nitap");
            System.out.print("Database is connected !");
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
            while(x==1)
            {
                System.out.println("Press 1 to enter student id");
                System.out.println("Press 2 to exit");
                Scanner s= new Scanner(System.in);
                int choice = s.nextInt();
                switch(choice)
                {
                case 1: System.out.println("Enter the ID of student");
                        int id = s.nextInt();

                        queryString = "select ID,Roll_no, Course_name, Course_code, Date,Time from student_reg where ID=" +id;
                        rs= stmt.executeQuery(queryString);
                        //System.out.println(rs.getInt("ID"));
                        while(rs.next())
                        {
                        if(rs.getInt("ID")== id)
                        {
                            String roll = rs.getString("Roll_no");
                            String date = rs.getString("Date");
                            String time =  rs.getString("Time");
                            String c_name = rs.getString("Course_name");
                            String c_code = rs.getString("Course_code");
                            password pass1= new password(roll,date,time,c_name,c_code);
                            pass= pass1.passwd();
                            System.out.println(pass);
                            queryString =" Update student_reg(Pass_word) set Pass_word = 'pass' where ID = ?";
                            //queryString= "INSERT INTO student_reg(Password) VALUES ('password') where ID = ?";
                            //stmt.executeUpdate(queryString);
                            //PreparedStatemenet pstmt = conn.preparedStatement("INSERT INTO student_reg(Password) VALUES ('password') where ID = ?");
                            //pstmt.setLong(1, id);

                            pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(queryString);

                            pstmt.setInt(1, id);
                            int numberOfUpdatedRecords = pstmt.executeUpdate();
                            s.close();
                        }
                        }
                        break;
                case 2: x=0;
                }
            }

            if(conn!= null)
            {
                stmt.close();
                pstmt.close();
            conn.close();
            conn = null;
            }
        }
            catch(ClassNotFoundException cnf)
            {
                 System.out.println("Driver could not be loaded: " + cnf);
            }
        catch(SQLException sqle)
        {
            System.out.println("SQL Exception thrown: " + sqle);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        System.out.print("Do not connect to DB - Error:"+e);
        }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is so obvious because you shouldn't include the 'id' in your query string:

```
queryString = "select ID,Roll_no, Course_name, Course_code, Date,Time from student_reg where ID = " + id;
```

Very good hint from @spencer: you can not use `WHERE` clause in your `INSERT INTO` statement. Probably you wanted to `UPDATE` a row with that id. Also it is better to do it using `PreparedStatemenet` to avoid such mistakes:

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/onlineexam","root", "batch12@nitap");
PreparedStatemenet pstmt = conn.preparedStatement("UPDATE student_reg SET password = 'password' where ID = ?");
pstmt.setLong(1, id);
int numberOfUpdatedRecords = pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

I suggest you to rename the column name `password`, because it is a reserved word in mysql, so you may get strange results working with that column name. Change it to some other thing like: `pass_word` or `passwd` , ... . As you may know you can use keywords as column names in your queries using some quotes or other things but it is more safe to rename it to another name, just for hint.

if you use this connection without a connection-pool, you may want to close the Statement and the Connection.

Good Luck.

Comment: WHERE clause is not supported in INSERT ... VALUES statement. (I suspect OP is intending to perform an UPDATE of an existing row. If OP is trying to insert new `id` value, that would be a value in the values list, not in a WHERE clause.)

Comment: Sir i changed my code to 
queryString =" Update student_reg(Password) set Password = ? where ID = ?";pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(queryString);
       pstmt.setString(1, password);
       pstmt.setInt(2, id);
       int numberOfUpdatedRecords = pstmt.executeUpdate();
but still getting the same exception

Comment: @vishnu priya, check it again, I updated the answer.

Comment: No sir, it still throwing the same exception

Comment: Please change your student_reg column name from password to passwd and try again. It must work. Also can you copy the exact exception?

Comment: ok, in your update query string you should omit the column name after table name: queryString =" Update student_reg set Pass_word = 'pass' where ID = ?";

Answer (score 2):

Your code has many problem:

```
queryString = "select ID,Roll_no, Course_name, Course_code, Date,Time from student_reg where ID= id";
```

This line you have condition where but you not set the value yet, you should set

```
queryString = "select ID,Roll_no, Course_name, Course_code, Date,Time from student_reg where ID = " + id;
```

Better if you take a look at [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) for prevent SQL Injection as well.

The last one:

```
queryString= "INSERT INTO student_reg(Password) VALUES ('password') where ID = id";
```

This line seem you want to update something. Please review it.

Answer (score 1):

```
queryString = "select ID,Roll_no, Course_name, Course_code, Date,Time from student_reg where ID= id";
```

should be

```
queryString = "select ID,Roll_no, Course_name, Course_code, Date,Time from student_reg where ID = " + id;
```

This would fix the error, but it would be better to use a PreparedStatement, where the query String looks like `"select ID,Roll_no, Course_name, Course_code, Date,Time from student_reg where ID = ?"`, and you pass the `id` as a parameter.

Comment: Sir I have updated my code. Can you plaese look at it again tell me where I am doing wrong because it is still giving the same exception.